# FW/1 not finding controller

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11, fw1

I recently updated my FW/1 app to version 3.5 and now the controllers functions aren't being called.

```
<!---@ Version History: 11 July 2011, Created by James Mohler --->
<!---@ Version History: 31 May 2013, Converted to Component by James Mohler --->



component accessors=true    {

property framework;
property beanFactory;

property reportService;
property historyService;
property uiService;
property payService;
property supportService;

void function before(required struct rc)    {   
    param rc.BossEID    = "all";
```

**Dump of variables**

[image]

Note that there are no functions on the controllers. No error message is shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ColdFusion style comments seems to change how the file is processed.

```
component accessors=true    {
```

doesn't do anything because the file is not in automatic `<cfscript>` mode.

Comment: I'd have to agree. You are mixing CFML with CFScript. Change your comments to script comments.

Comment: In addition, my two cents: remove your comments and let file versioning do that for you.